# Generating 1080p@30Hz from ADV7511

Tags: timing, hdmi

I am having trouble getting my ADV7511 chip to display data in 1080p@30Hz. I am using data pins 23-12 for 12-bit data as defined in Table 26 for Style 2 ([ADV7511 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/ADV7511_Programming_Guide.pdf)). I am following the timing diagram below from CEA-861-D exactly with a 75MHz pixel clock, which is slightly above the expected 74.25MHz clock.[image: 1080P timing diagram]

I am able to generate 720p@60Hz from the ADV7511 using the same settings I am trying to use for 1080p@30Hz which the only difference being the frame size/blanking.

**Edit**
Forgot to ask the question...

Why would the ADV7511 fail to display 1080p@30Hz on an ASUS display, which an error message of "OUT OF RANGE"?

Comment: `...I am following the timing diagram below from CEA-861-D exactly with a 75MHz pixel clock, which is slightly above the expected 74.25MHz clock....` Some devices, especially microcontrollers work only within a specific clock frequency. Go outside of that frequency and you can expect undesirable results.

Comment: @Mike, I guess I should have mentioned the reference design for my development board also uses 75MHz, it just doesn't 100% match the 74.25MHz spec'd in CEA-861-D. This is a clock I'm generating and sending to the ADV7511 synchronous to my data. The "correct" HDMI clock is generated by the ADV7511.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the text above contains only statements, and no question. I would guess that your current set up is not working and you want to know why.

I think it is essential to provide an exact 74.25MHz pixel rate, since the IC is capable to detect and re-shape the banking of the raw frames. This clock deviation may prevent the chip to detect the video mode, so it will not generate any output.

I would first check the 0x3E [7:2] register to see if the device detects any video mode.

Another guess, could be that your display does not support the 1080p@30 video mode. I have been using ADV7511 with Dell monitor, and it does not support any of the 30fps modes.

Comment: Oops. I've added the question. It doesn't seem like the minor difference in clock rate would cause the problem I'm seeing since the "incorrect" rate is used at 720p without any problem.

Comment: Are you sure your display supports 1080p@30?

Comment: Just tested it with a TV instead of a computer monitor and everything now works. I guess that's what you get for just assuming a 1080p HDMI monitor supports lower frequencies.

Comment: Just find the user guide for your monitor model and see the specs